# how to get this json output into php array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I want this `json` output into php array:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Roger",
            "country": "Switzerland",
            "city": "Basel"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Rafael",
            "country": "Spain",
            "city": "Madrid"
        },
    ]
}
```

I am trying this:

```php
$arrResult = array();
$arrResult['data'] = array();`

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){`
    $id = $row['id'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    $country = $row['country'];

    $arrResult['data'][] = array(
        'id'=> $id,
        'name'=> $name,
        'country'=> $country,
    );
}

echo json_encode($arrResult, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

I want the same output as given into `JSON` Format from a php array.

Comment: What **exactly** is not working with your code? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found your problem. Remove the comma in the json (explained in the code).

```
<?php
    $json = '{
        "data": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "Roger",
                "country": "Switzerland",
                "city": "Basel"
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "name": "Rafael",
                "country": "Spain",
                "city": "Madrid"
            }, <--- THIS IS A PROBLEM
        ]
    }';
    /* in order for this function to work you need to delete that comma. 
    Because there isn't another list in json so comma should not be there */

    $arrResult = json_decode($json, true);
    print_r($arrResult);
```

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e8a878f37c15218a8a113eafee99e5373c51d277 Check this link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json_decode()` if you are using PHP >= 5.2.0

Here is a sample on how to use `json_decode()`

```
<?php
  // JSON string
  $someJSON = '[{"name":"Shriram","gender":"male"},{"name":"Lexa","gender":"female"},{"name":"John Doe","gender":"male"}]';

  // Convert JSON string to Array
  $someArray = json_decode($someJSON, true);
  print_r($someArray);        // Dump all data of the Array
  echo $someArray[0]["name"]; // Access Array data

  // Convert JSON string to Object
  $someObject = json_decode($someJSON);
  print_r($someObject);      // Dump all data of the Object
  echo $someObject[0]->name; // Access Object data
?>
```

Comment: could you please took my json output and convert it to php array

Answer (score 0):

you can use the json_decode function.
example;

```
<?php
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';
echo $json;
$array = json_decode($json, true);
print_r($array);
?>
```

Comment: could you please took my json output and convert it to php array

Answer (score 0):

What I've understood is that you want to encode your array into the json format shown.

Use `json_encode($arrResult)` instead of `json_encode($arrResult, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)`.

`JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` outputs an object rather than an array.